# How to fetch all of my selected data and echo it with a while loop? Only fetching one record

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$sqlWork = "SELECT * FROM work WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'";     
$resultWork = $connection->query($sqlWork);
$rowWork = $resultWork->fetch_assoc();
```

### I currently have this table.

(I would add an image if I had the reputation)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmmar.jpg

### This is how I am outputting my data.

```
    do {         
        echo "{$rowWork['work']}";     
    } while ($description = mysqli_fetch_array($resultWork));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
while($rowWork = $resultWork->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $rowWork['work'];     
}
```

I see that you are not using parametrized query, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, you can avoid it by using prepared statement (parametrized)

Comment: About the parameterized query, I know I could search for it but do you have any link that could lead me right into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlWork = "SELECT * FROM work WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'";     
$resultWork = $connection->query($sqlWork);

while ($description = mysqli_fetch_array($resultWork)){
echo $description['work'];
}
```

Comment: Now this gives me all of the input. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this based on these:

```
foreach
```

Use when iterating through an array whose length is (or can be) unknown.

```
for
```

Use when iterating through an array whose length is set, or, when you need a counter.

```
while
```

Use when you're iterating through an array with the express purpose of finding, or triggering a certain flag.

Comment: Yes, I will start to use these more often. Thank you Dinesh.